# Admin Panel Grid - filter without column

Tags: adminhtml, grid, filter

Does it possible to create filter on grid without related column in grid? Now I'm using code like this:

```
<column name="name" sortOrder="30">
       <settings>
           <filter>text</filter>
           <label translate="true">Name</label>
       </settings>
</column>
```

Does Magento allow to this?

Comment: Can you please mention the magento version, purpose of the column etc.

Comment: I use Magento 2.3.5

Comment: Oof course you can create a filter without related column, by just defining your xml in UI Component, but why do you want to create a filter without related column?